# Hide a dropdown list from a thymeleaf form

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i have a thymeleaf form with tow dropdown list with a default value. I went to hide it form the form.

The first is :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="estado"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="estado" name="estado" class="form-control">
                        <option th:each="estado : ${estado}" th:value="${estado.idEstado}"
                            th:attr="choiceid=${estado.idEstado}" th:text="${estado.estado}"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the second is :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tipoDeDeclaracion"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <select th:field="*{tieneErrores}" class="form-control"
                        name="project_status">
                        <option value="N">NO (por defecto)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks resolve it by adding style="display: none;

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tipoDeDeclaracion"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <select th:field="*{tieneErrores}" class="form-control"
                        name="project_status">
                        <option value="N">NO (por defecto)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```